# Finding multiple words with find() in MongoDB

Tags: python, regex, mongodb

I'm using Python in conjunction with MongoDB. I have an array of words, and I use these words to search the Mongo database and match any documents with matching fields using `$in`, e.g.

```
collection.find({"word":{"$in":words}})
```

The above works very well, but I want to be able to use a regex. The problem is now that if one of the words in the array was spelt `accus` instead of `accuse`, I want the `find()` query to still return the document (record/row) relating to the word `accuse`.

I've tried this, which doens't work at all, no results are returned.

```
collection.find({"word":{"$in":{"$regex":words}}})
```

Each element in the array reads with `^` preceding the word, 
e.g. `['^work', '^accus', '^planet']`

Am I just going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry for late answer, just googled your question. You should use one regex, not an array of them, like:

```
'^[work|accus*|planet]'
```

Comment: Does this (`.find({"word":{"$in":{"$regex":"^anything.*$"}}})`) work? Not for me.. no results are returned.

Comment: Shouldn't the square brackets be round brackets as square brackets match against single characters?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `$regex` inside an `$in` expression, but you can use JS regex (the "/regex/" kind).

From the MongoDB docs at http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/operator/query/regex/#in-expressions:

> To include a regular expression in an $in query expression, you can only use JavaScript regular expression objects (i.e. /pattern/ ). You cannot use $regex operator expressions inside an $in.

BTW, I know it's a very late answer, but hopefully it'll serve the queriers of the future...

Answer (score 1):

Using Spring Data API, one can do the query as the following:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("words").in(Pattern.compile(regex-String)));
find(query)
```

This will find all the documents with an array field called `words` with element in that array that match the regex.

Answer (score 1):

According to Mongo [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/regex/#in-expressions) the currect way to this is the folllowing

```
var words = [/hello/, /^world/];// array of regex
db.getCollection('word collection').find({"word" : {$in : words}});
```

To accomplish this in `JS` you can create an array of `RegEXp` Objects and pass that array as the value of `$in` some thing like this :

```
words = words.map(function(v){return new RegExp(v)});
```