# Is it possible to use $all and $regex at the same time?

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

I've got an interesting problem that is somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345361/using-mongo-find-with-in-and-regex).  I have multiple values for a field that I want to check.  For example, say I want to look for a document with the field `name` matching "bob" and "barker".  Initially, I thought to do this:

```
db.TVHosts.find({ "name": { "$all" : 
   [ { "$regex": ".*bob.*" }, { "$regex" : ".*barker.*" } ] } })
```

The way to do it via the command line is to do this:

```
db.TVHosts.find({ "name": { "$all" : [ /.*bob.*/, /.*barker.*/ ] } })
```

But that didn't appear to work from Java.  Is there some key piece of documentation that I've missed?

EDIT: I'm using MongoDB via the MongoDB Java Driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Types), to send a Regex to MongoDB in Java you need to use `Pattern.compile` from `java.util.regex.Pattern`.